# Architecture for Intranet Application

Tags: html, wcf, jquery, service, architecture

I am planning to build a production application for a small & medium business. This is an intranet application with maximum 15 to 30 concurrent users. The proposed architecture is:

- Client: Firefox browser
- UI: HTML, JavaScript, CSS
- Communication via: jQuery AJAX
- Middle Tier: Window Service hosting WCF Service (using webHttpBinding)
- Database: SQLServer 2012 Express Edition

In this architecture the missing part is a WebServer that will serve the static HTML pages. I do not want to go in with IIS mainly because of the following reasons:

- Keep the cost of deployment down
- Most of work is being done in the Window Service hosting WCF Service

Since most of the middle tier work is done by my Window Service hosting WCF Service and my UI is HTML, JavaScript & CSS, can we do away with the WebServer like IIS or other WebServers supporting ASP.NET technology and use a lightweight WebServers which serves only static HTML pages something like lighttpd, nginx etc?

Are these light weight WebServers like lighttpd, nginx suitable to host in production environment.

There might be an issue of AJAX Cross Domain requests as Window Service hosting WCF Service and the lightweight WebServer may run on different port but on the same IP address. We can probably overcome this by opening it up to cross domain requests as it’s an intranet application.

One of the ideas behind this architecture is that I want to try and reuse this in other projects which are bigger in size.

Please let me know if this is possible and the related pros & cons of this approach. I am also open to any other suggestions which will help me improve this architecture.

Comment: I agree with Anders. Yuvi if you are hosting this on WCF how does this help with reuse in the future? You'll still be tied to windows (or at least .net) whether you use iis or not. I don't get what you're trying to do - this is just a web app, and MVC over IIS is exactly the right tool for the job, unless you want to go with node.js or something.

Comment: Hugh, in any n-tier application you would need some kind of middle tier. This could be either a plain Windows Service, a Windows Service hosting WCF or a WebServer like IIS. 

The above example is just a starting point. I am trying to develop an architecture that will help me reuse for bigger scale projects.  One of the reasons I want to do away with IIS is the cost involved. If I have my own service there is no cost involved.

Comment: But what cost are you trying to avoid? Are you talking about windows server licensing costs?

Comment: Yes I would like to avoid the windows server license cost involved with IIS. What I want to do I provide the solution to the customer where he does not have to shell out any additional cost on the Software Licenses apart form the application that I will build.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overdesigning it for such a small site. If you're anyway going to run a WCF service it shouldn't be a problem to use IIS.

I'd suggest to either use ASP.NET MVC and do the html rendering on the server, or to go for a client side library such as angular.js in combination with Web API.

Comment: Anders, thanks for the input, but I want to avoid IIS or any WebServer which supports ASP.NET technology totally. The idea here is to use Windows Service hosting WCF Service to do the middle tier work. So now the question is how do I server the static HTML... so for this can I use these lightweight webservers like lighttpd, nginx .

Comment: Why do you want to avoid IIS? And why are you willing to use WCF in that case? WCF isn't exactly lightweight.

Comment: Hmm.. that is a valid point. For this example, this architecture is probably an over design. The long term idea is to build a generic architecture which I can reuse for my future projects as well. So that is the  reason I want Windows Service/WCF to do all my work and get a lightweight webserver to serve the HTML.

Comment: While I do like the intention to make reusable work I think you should first build an application using the standard tools to learn how they work and what their flaws are before inventing something improved.

Comment: Well Anders, this isn't exactly my first application. I have fair amount of experience dealing with these technologies. This reason I posted this question was that I indeed wanted to experiment with new ideas. And I do agree I could not put all that in the question above. So with this background if you could put in your thoughts for the question I have asked above.